# Unable to use async await with sequelize.authenticate() method

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

The SQL password expires every 24 hour once (The interval might change anytime without prior notice), hence I want to validate the authentication using Sequelize beforeConnect hook before I run a SQL query.

Without async await the SQL query will fail and then authenticate and the preceding queries will pass. I want to run the code async way so no SQL queries fail. Kindly help me fix this problem.

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, params);

    sequelize.beforeConnect(async (currConfig) => {
        try {
            await sequelize.authenticate();
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: The application breaks no proper error message is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can promisify the beforeConnect

```
let currConfig = await prepare(sequelize);
try {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
}

function prepare(sequelize) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    sequelize.beforeConnect(config => res(config));
  });
}
```

Just make sure your function has `async` infront of it

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response, The try catch method will be triggered only for the first time. I want the sequelize.authenticate() to be validated every time sequelize.beforeConnect hook is executed.

Comment: Can't you "thennify" it in that cast? `sequelize.beforeConnect(...).then(() => sequelize.authenticate())` ? Just a hunch

Comment: @Tikkes it actually is. you can `prepare(sequelize).then(config => sequelize.authenticate())`

Comment: Tried the same but ended up getting below error.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart